# How to vectorize a pandas dataframe calculation where if a conditional is not met the data from the previous row is entered?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization

Currently I am using a for loop with a conditional that when true performs a calculation and inputs it into the column of a dataframe. However, when the conditional is not met the data from the previous row is entered into the new row.

This is a pseudocode of what I currently have:

```
for index in range(len(dataframe[column1])):
  if condition==True:
    dataframe.at[index, column3]= dataframe.at[index, column1]-dataframe.at[index, column2]
  else:
    dataframe.at[index, column3]= dataframe.at[index-1, column3]
```

I understand that when the calculation of the current row depends on the previous row, vectorization usually is not viable. However in this case, since the calculation for column 3 does not depend on the previous row and I am simply inputting the previous row's value into the current row, would it be possible to vectorize this to improve runtime speed?

Comment: Hey Lucas, can you provide a data frame consisting of a few rows and the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that in a vectorized way like this.

**Starting Data**

```
   c0  c1  c2
0   5   2   4
1   5  10   6
2   9   3   2
3   1   4   2
4   4   2   7
5   1   5   8
6   3   4   6
7  10   1   3
8   4   2   6
9   3   1   2
```

**Execute**

```
import numpy as np

dfc = df.assign(c3=np.where(df['c0']>2, df['c1']-df['c2'], np.nan)).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(dfc)
```

**Result**

```
   c0  c1  c2  c3
0   5   2   4  -2
1   5  10   6   4
2   9   3   2   1
3   1   4   2   1
4   4   2   7  -5
5   1   5   8  -5
6   3   4   6  -2
7  10   1   3  -2
8   4   2   6  -4
9   3   1   2  -1
```

This leverages Numpy's `where` function to do the selection. If the condition is true then it does the subtraction.  If not true it places an `NA` value temporarily into the cell. Then `ffill` does a forward fill of values which completes the logic of placing the previous value of the column into a cell if the condition is not true.  Note that `fillna(0)` place a zero in the first row if the condition is not met in the first row - since it does not have a previous value to place.