# Pandas dataframe calculations refers to previous row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi apologies for this question being asked again but i can not find a solution in all the previous versions of this question.

I am trying to vectorise a pandas calculation where the previous row is used as a value and is effected by the same calculation.

I am doing back testing on a trading strategy and i currently have a df with all trade sizes, price movements, etc. I am trying to reduce my trade size when the risk exceeds the max risk.

| Trade Open | Trade number | Trade size | stop | close | risk | max risk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | 1 | 100% | 80 | 100 | 20.00% | 20% |
|  | 1 | 100% | 80 | 120 | 33.33% | 20% |
|  | 1 | 100% | 80 | 140 | 42.86% | 20% |
|  | 1 | 100% | 80 | 160 | 50.00% | 20% |

i am try to create a calculation that when "risk" exceeds "max risk" a reduction is made to "Trade size" and the calculation going forward uses the new "Trade size".

Desired outcome

| Trade Open | Trade number | Trade size | stop | close | risk | max risk | Reduction boolean | Reduction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | 1 | 100% | 80 | 100 | 20.00% | 20% | FALSE | 0% |
|  | 1 | 100% | 80 | 120 | 33.33% | 20% | TRUE | 40% |
|  | 1 | 60% | 80 | 140 | 25.71% | 20% | TRUE | 22% |
|  | 1 | 46.8% | 80 | 160 | 23.40% | 20% | TRUE | 15% |

My current codes is looking similar to this, which is incorrect due due to the circular calculations of "Trade_size', which then creates incorrect risk calculations.

```
d = {'Trade Open': [True, False, False, False,], 'Trade number': [1]*4, 'Trade_size': [100]*4, 'close':[100,120,140,160],'stop': [80]*4, 'max_risk': [20]*4}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['risk'] = (df.close - df.stop)/ df.close * df.Trade_size
df['reduction_boolean'] = df.risk > df.max_risk
df['reduction'] = 0 
df.loc[df['reduction_boolean'], 'reduction'] = 1 - (df.max_risk / df.risk)

df.loc[df['reduction_boolean'].shift() == True, 'Trade_size'] = df.Trade_size * (1-df.reduction.shift())
df
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered suggestions from [Pandas how to vectorize a calculation that relies on previous rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73848700/12846804)? A `np.convolve` that does it... but is not necessarily faster.
(+ maybe post links to previous iteration(s) of the question?)

Comment: Have you considered `.assign`, although unsure this could be called vectorization? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73042532/12846804

Answer (score 0):

I think i have solved my problem but i would like to hear anyones thoughts on my way of working around it.

```
d = {'Trade Open': [True, False, False, False,False], 'Trade number': [1]*5, 'Trade_size': [100]*5, 'close':[100,120,140,160,120],'stop': [80]*5, 'max_risk': [20]*5}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.loc[ (((df['Trade_size'].shift() * ((df.close - df.stop)/df.close))) > df.max_risk), 'max_Trade_size'] = df.max_risk / (df['Trade_size'].shift() * ((df.close - df.stop)/df.close)) * 100

df.loc[df.max_Trade_size.shift() < df.Trade_size, 'Trade_size'] = df.max_Trade_size.shift() 

df['risk'] = (df.close - df.stop)/ df.close * df.Trade_size
df['reduction_boolean'] = df.risk > df.max_risk

df['reduction'] = (df['Trade_size'].shift() - df['Trade_size']) / df['Trade_size'].shift()
df.loc[df['reduction'] < 0 , 'reduction'] = 0
df['reduction'] = df['reduction'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df['reduction'].isna(), 'reduction'] = 0 
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using np.where and compared it with your approach using %time. Here are the results I got.

df.loc approach:

```
%timeit df.loc[df['reduction_boolean'], 'reduction'] = 1 - (df.max_risk / df.risk)
909 µs ± 60.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[df['reduction_boolean'].shift() == True, 'Trade_size'] = df.Trade_size * (1-df.reduction.shift())
1.18 ms ± 72.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

np.where approach:

```
%timeit df['reduction']=1-(df['max_risk']/df['risk'])
726 µs ± 27.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit df['Trade_size']=np.where(df['reduction_boolean'].shift()==True,df['Trade_size'] * (1-df['reduction'].shift()),df['Trade_size'])
739 µs ± 30.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```